# How to use Symbol Image with Image on macOS 15.15

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

`Image`'s initializer with `systemname` does not work on macOS 15.15, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(systemname:)

The workaround is to use an exported image set, however, I got an "No image named 'IMAGE_NAME' found in asset catalog for main bundle" error when I use an exported SF Symbol SVG file. I tried a normal `.png` file and it would work with `Image` and have no problem to find it inside `Assets.xcassets`.

Do you have any idea why the symbol image could not be found?

[image]

Comment: It is just not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Symbol Image is not supported on macOS 15.15. The workaround I end up with is converting SF Symbol into SVG and then make them PDF before drag-and-drop in `Assets.xcassets`.

[image]